# Из символов * cделать пирамиду

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Помогите написать программу (не полностью, а подсказать),** которая выводит из символов `*` делают пирамиду

[image: 123]

*формат ввода:* Одно целое число - высота пирамиды (для картинки это число `3`).
*Формат вывода:* Пирамида в формате, аналогичном показанному в примере.

Я ещё очень зелёный в этой теме, поэтому пока туплю... Написал вот это(бред, но я пытался)

```
x=int(input())
for i in range(x):
    print('*'*x)
```

Используется python 3.6

Comment: Осталось слева пробелы добавлять

Comment: Я пошел вообще другим путем - выравнивание символов по левому краю\центру\правому краю... т.е. есть некая переменная, которая равна желаемой ширине пирамидки. Ну ок, строим пирамидку, и выравниваем по какому нужно параметру. Если нужно решение - сброшу, но подсказка более чем очевидна.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
x=int(input())
for i in range(x):
    print('%s%s' % (' ' * (x-i-1), '*' * (i*2+1)))
```

Comment: а что значит '%s%s'  ?

Comment: @coooooler, https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/formatirovanie-strok-operator.html

Comment: огромное спасибо)))

Comment: можно чуть проще: `for i in range(n): print(' ' * (n-i-1) +  '*' * (i*2+1))`

Comment: @jfs, можно плюс на запятую заменить еще. По идее, так результат будет отправляться в stdout без лишнего конката (у меня в ответе соответственно лишнее форматирование). Но тут странные ответы и вопрос со словом "зеленый", что можно трактовать двояко, поэтому править ответ и поднимать вопрос на главную не нужно, наверное.

Comment: запятая здесь неправильный результат даст, когда ноль пробелов должно быть.

Comment: @jfs, попробовал, вроде, нормально с запятой и нулем пробелов.

Comment: сохраните результат одно варианта кода в один файл, другого — в другой файл (`> "result${i}.txt"`) и сравните `diff result*.txt`

Comment: @jfs, правда, запятая добавляет пробел. Я и забыл.

Answer (score 6):

Я читаю вашу картинку слева направо, но *только по отвесную ось симметрии*:

> ```
>   *   -   2 пробелы,  1 звездочка 
>  **   -   1 пробел,   2 звездочки  
> ***   -   0 пробелов, 3 звездочки
> ```

Пробелов убывает, звездочек прибывает, но сумма пробелов и звездочек всегда `3`
(в общем случае это `x`).

Пусть количество звездочек будет в переменной `i`.

И так как `i` меняется от `1` по `x` (здесь `x` равно `3`), вы можете писать:

> `*   -   (x - 1) пробелов, 1 звездочка         (i == 1 в этой итерации)`
>   `**   -   (x - 2) пробелов, 2 звездочки         (i == 2 в этой итерации)`
>  `***   -   (x - 3) пробелов, 3 звездочки         (i == 3 в этой итерации)`

Значит, мы будем пользоваться циклом

```
for i in range(1, x + 1):
```

причем число звездочек будет `i` и число пробелов `(x - i)`.

---

Да, я пока читал вашу картину *только по отвесную ось*, но прибавить *остальные звездочки* не будет проблема — или будет? (Всегда о `1` менее чем до отвесной оси.)

```
for i in range(1, x + 1):
    spaces = (x - i) * ' '
    asterisks = i * '*' + (i - 1) * '*'
    print(f'{spaces}{asterisks}')
```

---

*Примечание:*

`f`   (в Python 3.6+) непосредственно перед

- начальным апострофом, или
- начальной кавычкой

строки обозначает [f-строку](https://shultais.education/blog/python-f-strings) (форматированную).

Answer (score 4):

@HasmikGaryaka Зачем править мой ответ?
Для @MarianD, вот решение более гибкое:

```
x = int(input())
i=1
width = x+(x-1)
for i in range(1,x+1):
    print("{0:^{1}.{2}}".format("*"*(i+(i-1)), width, width))
```

метод format() очень гибкий. Здесь "^" - выравнивание по центру, по умолчанию заполнитель - пробелы. В {1}(минимальная длина) {2}(максимальная длина) подставляется переменная width, в которой рассчитана длина поля исходя из количества строк, введённых пользователем.

Answer (score 0):

Пиши код, исходя из того, что в первой строке x-1 пробел и одна звездочка, а с каждой новой строкой убирается один пробел и добавляется две звездочки.

То есть:

```
x = int(input())
k = 1
for i in range(x):
    print(' '*(x-1-i),'*'*k, sep='')
    k += 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот решил эту задачку таким образом:

```
height = int(input('Высота пирамиды: '))
for j in range(1, height + 1):
  for i in range(height * 2 + 1):
    if i == height:
      print('#' * (j * 2 - 1), end = "")
      height -= 1
    else:
      print(' ', end = "")
  print()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
x = int(input(": "))
c = (x - 1) * 2 + 1
for i in range(x):
    print((('*' * i) * 2 + '*').center(c)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
height = int(input())
for i in range(1, height + 1):
    stars = 2 * i - 1
    spaces = height - i
```

Ну и дальше print()